# Sorting and accessing elements in lists with 100000 elements

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I know I should use `NumPy` with big arrays like the list I have, but I can't because I am solving a problem on Kattis (a site with problems, where you have to submit the code and they compile it) and submitting the code with line `import numpy` gives a run time error. 
I think the process that takes the most time is me reading and sorting all the data. I read and sort it like this:

```
def readData():
    import sys
    lines = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
    points = [tuple([int(num) for num in line.split(" ")]) for line in lines] #we have a list of tuples: [(x1, y1), ... (xn, yn)]
    sortedBySums = sorted(points, key = lambda x: (sum(x), x[0]))
    sortedBySub = sorted(points, key = lambda x: (sub(x), x[0]))
```

Later on I also access the elements of tables `sortedBySums` and `sortedBySubs`, so maybe I could also speed the lookup, but don't know how. I am using `list.index(element)` for element lookup. Also, the `sub(x)` function just subtracts the second coordinate from the first one.

Is there any way I could speed this process up? The `sort` build in function should be really fast, from what I have learned and using the `for loop` like this should also be a lot faster than using regular `for loop`, but is there anything else that could drastically improve time consumption?

Comment: What you have is already pretty fast. You could save a little by skipping the intermediate `lines` list... `points = [tuple([int(num) for num in line.strip().split(" ")]) for line in sys.stdin]`. And it may be worth indexing the lists like `sortedBySumsIndex = {(element, i) for i, element in enumerate(sortedBySums)}` if you look up by element a lot. But it already looks fast to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
points = [(int(line[i]), int(line[i+1])) for i in range(0,len(line)-1,2) for line in sys.stdin]
```

instead of:

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin]
points = [tuple([int(num) for num in line.split(" ")]) for line in lines] #we have a list of tuples: [(x1, y1), ... (xn, yn)]
```

Comment: Could I bother you to vote your conscience on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared, hey it's a great answer!

Comment: Thanks (-: I'm trying to strategize about a few things and see if it works.